# Where netbeans saves attached sources (JavaDoc, Sources)

Tags: java, netbeans, javadoc

When i read a class from any library attached to my project i can download sources like: (javadoc and sources), so in which folder netbeans saves this resources?
[image]

Comment: Are you using Maven?

Comment: No, i am not using maven.

Comment: As far as I know the button to download sources and javadocs are only available in Maven based projects. For Ant based projects you provide the sources and javadocs yourself when you (manually) define the library.

Comment: Yes, i have download manually my sources, but the question is, when i import sources, where netbeans saves them.

Comment: What do you mean with "when I import sources"? How exactly do you do that? Can you add a screenshot of the dialog you use? What is the menu you use to use that feature?

Comment: Added a screenshot

Comment: That button selects an _existing_ file or directory that _you_ created. It does not "download" anything

Comment: Okay, i any case, when netbeans saves these resources

Comment: It doesn't save it, it _uses_ an existing file that you provide. **You** save that file, not NetBeans

Comment: Okay thank you. In any case, when i download it with maven project, when it saves resources?

Comment: Then it's downloaded by maven into the local maven repository, typically `%HOMEPATH%\.m2` in Windows

Comment: Okay thank you for clarify me download/attach sources options.!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to distinguish between two situations:

#### Native, Ant based projects

In that case, **you** provide the location of the sources and JavaDocs *manually*. It's your responsibility to download and store them somewhere on your hard disk. NetBeans does not download anything, you just tell NetBeans where to find them.

#### Maven based projects

The sources and JavaDocs are downloaded by Maven and stored in the local Maven repository. On Linux this is `~/.m2` (I think) and on Windows the default location is `%homepath%\.m2`

You can also use manually downloaded sources and JavaDocs in a Maven based project. This can e.g. be done from within the project Window:

[image]

In that case it's again your responsibility to download and store the files somewhere.